# React. Показать блок при изменении поля input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два одинаковых input. При изменении одного должна показываться подсказка. Сейчас у меня эта подсказка выпадает в двух местах, вместо одного...я думал сделать идентификацию каждой из подсказок и каждого инпута, но мне кажется, что это не совсем гибко. Возможно вы сможете что-нибудь подсказать?
Заранее благодарен

```
const location = [
    "Kharkiv",
    "Kyiv",
    "Odessa",
    "Lviv"
];

export default location;



import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';
import location from "../../data/location";

class SearchResults extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isFocused: false,
            isCollapsed: true,
            isChecked: true,
            pickupLocation: "",
            returnLocation: ""
        };
    }

    handleCheckbox = () => {
        this.setState({
            isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
        });
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            isFocused: true
        });
    };

    handleBlur = () => {
      this.setState({
          isFocused: false
      });
    };

    getSuggestion = () => {
        return <ul className="">
            {location.map((item, key) => <li key={key}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="search">
                <p className="search__title">Pickup</p>

                <div className="search__group">
                    <div className="search__group--location">
                        <input type="text"
                               name="pickup-location"
                               onChange={this.handleChange}
                               onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                               placeholder="Country, City"/>
                        {this.state.isFocused && this.getSuggestion()}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="search__group">
                    <div className="search__group--date double">
                        <input type="date"/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="search__group--time double">
                        <input type="time"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p className="search__title">Return</p>

                <div className="search__group checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           id="location"
                           checked={this.state.isChecked}
                           onChange={this.handleCheckbox}/>
                    <label htmlFor="location">
                        <span>Return to pickup location</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className={(!this.state.isChecked ? " " : "hide")}>

                    <div className="search__group">
                        <div className="search__group--location">
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="return-location"
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                                   placeholder="Country, City"/>
                            {this.state.isFocused && this.getSuggestion()}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div className="search__group">
                    <div className="search__group--date double">
                        <input type="date"/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="search__group--time double">
                        <input type="time"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


}

export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: При изменении текстовых или чекбоксов?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov текстовых. "Country, city"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - проверять имя input'а:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.name === 'нужныйИнпут' && e.target.value.length > 0) {
        this.setState({
            isCollapsed: true
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: я вот тоже думал делать так, но как считаете, это гибкое решение или не очень?

Comment: Что означает гибкое? У вас весьма упрощенный пример. Сложно сказать, куда он будет развиваться. Можно сделать отдельные хендлеры на каждый инпут. Можно посылать имя поля через .bind и т.д.

Comment: это не работет, так-как мне нужно, чтоб при вводе текста в конкретный инпут блок с подсказкой появлялся возле этого конкретного инпута.

Comment: Тогда сделайте реакт-компонент, содержащий input и блок подсказки, потом в приложении разместите сколько влезет таких компонентов и каждый будет отрабатывать только для своего стейта

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: сделал, спасибо вам